# How to hide a row that containing more than one empty cell?

Tags: jquery

For the table below, row2 and row3 have more than 1 empty cell(`<td></td>`), how can I use jQuery to check if each row in the table have more than 1 empty cell, than hide that row accordingly?

#### UPDATED:

If I want to check if each row(td) contain more than ONE cell(td) that is containing JUST witespace, than hide that row?

Thanks

```
<table>
<tr class="row1">
<td>a</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>c</td>
<td>d</td>
</tr>
<tr class="row2">
<td>a</td>
<td>b</td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr class="row3">
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td>c</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
...
<tr class="row100">
<td>a</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>c</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In actual use, "empty" cells often contain all kinds of whitespace.  EG: `<td> </td>`, `<td> \n </td>`, `<td>&nbsp;</td>`, `<td class="Invalid"></td>`, etc.
[See how easy it is to break](http://jsfiddle.net/CtPjq/)?

A more robust solution handles real-life HTML:

```
$('table tr').filter ( function () {
    var blankCells  = $(this).html ().match (/<td[^<>]*>(?:\s|&nbsp;)*<\/td>/ig);
    var numBlank    = blankCells ? blankCells.length : 0;
    return numBlank > 1;
} ).hide ();
```

[**See the demo at jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/CtPjq/2/)

Note that this solution is probably fine for most practical cases, but since it uses regex to parse the DOM (even a little), it could end up showing extra rows if the HTML was coded poorly.

Comment: You should use `text()` so you [don't need to deal with `&nbsp;`](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/7vHTe/).

Comment: @BrockAdams: Why work with `innerHTML` instead of the DOM anyway?

Comment: `text()` strips out the `td` tags; makes it very hard to count cells.

Comment: @Alex, The solution is simple, straightforward, **works** and is not parsing the DOM, merely filtering blanks.

Comment: @BrockAdams: ...Until that `td` has attributes. What I was getting at is that the DOM exists to be parsed - you then serialise it to a string and parse that - why?

Comment: @Alex: You're right, it wouldn't have handled attributes. Fixed. (Except for bad-practice, edge-case JS, maybe.).  This approach is more straightforward and more efficient than the other.  It will handle all cases that my teams/shops will encounter, and probably the OP's as well.  **If** an edge-case *does* appear, the worst case is that an extra row is displayed.

Comment: @alex let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1395/discussion-between-brock-adams-and-alex)

Answer (score 4):

> How can I use jQuery to check if each row in the table have more than 2 empty cell, than hide that row accordingly?

You can use [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).

```
$('table tr').filter(function() {
    return $(this).children('td:empty').length > 2;
}).hide();
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/dTQ7j/).

### Update

> If I want to check if each row(td) contain more than ONE cell(td) that is containing JUST whitespace, than hide that row?

I *think* this is what you now want...

```
$('table tr').filter(function() {
    var valid = $(this).children('td').filter(function() { 
        return ! $(this).text().replace(/\s/g, '').length;
    }).length;
    
    return valid > 1;
}).hide();
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/ttWCA/).

Comment: +1 for the same answer. I was busy *fiddling*. See it in action - http://jsfiddle.net/NQURB/

Comment: @jason he wants it greater than 2, so `> 2` not `> 1`

Comment: @JasonMcCreary: Only problem is, the OP says *have more than 2 empty cell* :P

Comment: Ah, yes. Thought it read 2 or more (I wasn't the only one **alex** :) - http://jsfiddle.net/NQURB/1/

Comment: I was a'fiddlin but gave up quite quickly. Very nice, compact code!

Comment: @JasonMcCreary: Hehe, yeah :)

Comment: @CharlesYeung: I've updated my answer, in the future, you should clearly outline your question first instead of changing the question all together 30 mins after asking.

Comment: @BrockAdams: I forgot the `g` flag on the regex.

Comment: OK, I should have checked closer when adding `&nbsp;` broke it.  Deleted my earlier comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("tr").each(function() {
  var i = 0;
  $(this).children("td").each(function() {
    if (!$(this).html()) {
      i++;
    }
    if (i > 2) {
      $(this).parent().hide();
      return false;     
    }
  });
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fT9VQ/1/

Alex's answer is probably better.